# Overlap div past container with clearfix mixen overflow:hidden

Tags: singularitygs

I've recently updated to SingularityGS 1.4.0 and have run into an issue with my `.container` class using an `@include clearfix;` which now includes an `overflow:hidden` property.

For a slideshow component, I use negative/positive margins to display arrows overlapping arrows outside of the `.container`:

```
.container {  //Container for the grid system 
    background: $background-color;        
    max-width: $site-width;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    @include clearfix;
    @include breakpoint($large-break) {
        border-left: 20px solid #fff;
        border-right: 20px solid #fff; 
        width: $site-width; 
    }

    .container {
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        clear: both;
    }
}


    .left-arrow, .right-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: -20px;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: 41px;
        height: 41px;
        top: 50%;
    }
    .left-arrow {
        left: -10px;
        background: url(/images/icons.png) no-repeat -153px -146px;
    }
    .right-arrow {
        right: -10px;
        background: url(/images/icons.png) no-repeat -197px -146px;
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl4ch4yowe61kz7/Screenshot%202014-09-03%2010.06.50.png?dl=0

Should I be using something other then the clearfix mixin in my container?

**Edit:**  - Added [Sassmeister issue as requested](http://sassmeister.com/gist/bc09c9dec57cb4a4421e)

Comment: Please try and recreate your issue using http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: [Sassmeister issue as requested](http://sassmeister.com/gist/bc09c9dec57cb4a4421e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of Singularity uses the Compass clearfix. You can write your own to work as you want it:

```
@mixin clearfix {
    &:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
    }
}
```

see: http://sassmeister.com/gist/099ef72b56365fe8ce07

Comment: Thanks Scott!  This helped me discover the [Compass pie-clearfix mixen](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/#mixin-pie-clearfix) which "allows positioned elements to hang outside the bounds of the container at the expense of more tricky CSS."

Comment: Singularity 1.4 actually [does come with a clearfix mixin](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/blob/1.x.x/stylesheets/singularitygs/helpers/_clearfix.scss). If you would like to use it, import Singularity after Compass. If you want to use your own, declare it after your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Singularity doesn't have its own clearfix mixin.

You're using the `clearfix` mixin from Compass which leverages the `overflow: hidden` technhique which in turn crops your container.

The solution is to use another mixin for clearfixing.

Compass bundles [three different clearfix](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/) mixins, the most usable of which is the `pie-clearfix`. It's output is as follows:

```
.foo {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.foo:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

I recommend that you use the `clearfix` mixin bundled with the beautiful [toolkit](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit) Sass extension by Team Sass.

It has the following benefits over the `pie-clearfix`:

1. Shorter output that works for all modern browsers:

   ```
   .foo:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
   ```
2. Two ways of applying: the traditional mixin way (default) and the extend way. The extend way makes your CSS footprint even smaller by deduplication. The downside of the extend way is not being able to apply it from media queries, though i've never faced a situation where you would need a clearfix only in a media query and need it not to be applied outside media query.

   To configure Toolkit for using the extend way apply this in the beginning of your CSS:

   ```
   @include toolkit-set('clearfix extend', false);
   ```

   To override current setting once use this:

   ```
   @include clearfix(true);
   ```

   `true` means the extend methhod, `false` means the mixin method.

Note that if you're including both Compass and Toolkit, Toolkit should come after Compass to override the `clearfix` mixin.

If you feel that Toolkit is too bulky for your project, simply define your own `clearfix` mixin after importing Compass, just like Scott [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25654235/901944). Just be sure to use proper clearfix method, Scott's code (as of 2014-09-04 12:00 UTC) doesn't actually clearfix.